# KTorrent and ufw: firewall problems

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw, bittorrent, ktorrent

I am at my wits' end and cannot get KTorrent to download under my current `ufw` settings. I am using Kubuntu 16.04.

As I understand from reading the configuration window, KTorrent uses the following ports

- 6881
- UDP tracker: 8881 UDP
- Representative server (system language is not English and have to translate this: it is the next option under network on the left) HTT "use KDE representative server." Port 8080 shows up in a greyed out box.
- DHT port 7881.

I have been trying for hours to find the correct `ufw` rules. Here is the output of `ufw status numbered`.

```
 Vers                       Action      De
 ----                       ------      --
[ 1] 25/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 2] 53/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 3] 80,110,443,465,587/tcp     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 4] 53,67,68/udp               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 5] 143,993/tcp                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 6] 47638/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 7] 47638/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 8] 7881/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 9] 7881/udp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[10] 8080/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[11] 8080/udp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[12] 6881                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[13] 8881/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[14] 25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[15] 53/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[16] 80,110,443,465,587/tcp (v6) ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[17] 53,67,68/udp (v6)          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[18] 6881/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[19] 6881/udp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[20] 143,993/tcp (v6)           ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[21] 47638/tcp (v6)             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[22] 47638/udp (v6)             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[23] 7881/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[24] 7881/udp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[25] 8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[26] 8080/udp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[27] 6881 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[28] 8881/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Before making these rules, I set my default incoming and outgoing to deny, following this [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/Firewall). The minute I disable `ufw`, everything works again.

Edit: Here are is a hopefully reprsentative sample of the output of `grep "7881" /var/log/ufw.log`. It seems to be the source during many blocking events, even though I have it set as open. I must be misinterpreting the logs. Port 8080 isn't mentioned anywhere in them, though.

```
Jun 29 21:05:11 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16073.180993] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=45.58.99.71 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32239 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=23935 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:05:11 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16073.181016] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=45.58.99.71 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32240 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=23935 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:05:11 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16073.181056] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=84.80.41.91 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40119 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=51413 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:05:11 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16073.181076] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=84.80.41.91 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40120 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=51413 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:05:41 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16103.314240] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=45.55.188.47 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=59088 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=6881 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.982845] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=73.207.219.79 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=26113 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=8999 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.982886] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=73.207.219.79 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=26114 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=8999 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.982941] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=185.45.195.189 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=5856 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=28066 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.982969] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=185.45.195.189 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=5857 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=28066 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.983012] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=163.172.36.40 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35696 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=6881 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.983036] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=163.172.36.40 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35697 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=6881 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.983078] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=45.58.99.71 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34462 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=23935 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.983100] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=45.58.99.71 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34463 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=23935 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.983142] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=84.80.41.91 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=44596 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=51413 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:10:31 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16394.983167] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=84.80.41.91 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=44597 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=51413 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:11:01 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16425.116434] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=45.55.188.47 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22519 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=6881 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:12:32 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16515.752536] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=73.207.219.79 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=37743 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=8999 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:13:02 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16545.886059] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=45.55.188.47 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22567 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=6881 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:14:32 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16636.536352] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=73.207.219.79 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=46899 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=8999 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:14:32 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16636.536446] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=73.207.219.79 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=46900 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=8999 LEN=102 
Jun 29 21:14:32 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [16636.536592] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=185.45.195.189 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35622 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7881 DPT=28066 LEN=102
```

Here are some incoming events

```
Jun 29 20:47:42 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [15019.998495] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=94:e9:79:de:0e:6b:a0:63:91:04:52:68:08:00 SRC=187.127.184.39 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=293 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=31463 PROTO=UDP SPT=10923 DPT=7881 LEN=273 
Jun 29 20:47:43 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [15021.147024] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=94:e9:79:de:0e:6b:a0:63:91:04:52:68:08:00 SRC=123.203.64.166 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=293 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=1847 PROTO=UDP SPT=7510 DPT=7881 LEN=273 
Jun 29 20:48:08 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [15045.794512] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=94:e9:79:de:0e:6b:a0:63:91:04:52:68:08:00 SRC=213.136.79.27 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=125 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=8251 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51441 DPT=7881 LEN=105 
Jun 29 20:48:20 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [15057.622817] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=94:e9:79:de:0e:6b:a0:63:91:04:52:68:08:00 SRC=79.97.64.25 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=132 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=49 ID=42367 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=7881 LEN=112 
Jun 29 20:49:16 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [15113.782068] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=94:e9:79:de:0e:6b:a0:63:91:04:52:68:08:00 SRC=213.136.79.205 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=125 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=2902 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7186 DPT=7881 LEN=105 
Jun 29 20:49:51 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [15148.855060] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=94:e9:79:de:0e:6b:a0:63:91:04:52:68:08:00 SRC=213.136.79.27 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=125 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=26442 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51467 DPT=7881 LEN=105 
Jun 29 20:50:05 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [15163.009876] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=94:e9:79:de:0e:6b:a0:63:91:04:52:68:08:00 SRC=213.136.79.7 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=125 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=61420 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=11928 DPT=7881 LEN=105 
Jun 29 20:50:19 stefan-Aspire-F5-573T kernel: [15177.038100] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=94:e9:79:de:0e:6b:a0:63:91:04:52:68:08:00 SRC=213.136.79.205 DST=192.168.1.4 LEN=125 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=13626 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=7186 DPT=7881 LEN=105
```

I opened port 8999 incoming UDP and can now **download torrents that are already started**. That is, if I disable the firewall, start downloading and enable, the downloads will now continue. If stopped, they will not resume. Also, magnet links will not download while the firewall is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [ufw logs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Interpreting_Log_Entries)?

You should first enable them if not already. And I wonder if you should be adding 7881/tcp IN rule & 8080/tcp IN rules as well - but that's to be answered after checking your logs. After enabling logs, try quitting & re-opening ktorrent, as it should check for port 8080 on startup (probably), which then should lead to some entries in ufw logs.

Comment: I have looked at the logs and edited my question with what I found.

Comment: But 7881 IN is not in your allow list, just OUT.

Comment: But on the other hand, you're right about the out blockage on 7881 UDP, I'm baffled at that point, as it's already open.

Comment: Perhaps the log entries are due the phenomenon described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/299964/why-is-ufw-logging-block-messages-regarding-a-port-for-which-ufw-is-configured?rq=1