# Ufw blocking packages that should be allowed in configuration

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

I have 2 servers running `Ubuntu 16.04`.
Server 1 has ip `10.100.100.101` and server 2 has ip `10.100.100.102`.
Server 1 has Ufw enabled and should accept all traffic to port `8080` from server 2. (Server 2 has Apache that proxies traffic to Server 1.) For some reason Ufw sometimes blocks packages going to port 8080. Version of Ufw is `0.35`.
I have tried resetting Ufw settings and rebooting servers but that made no difference.
Apache logs on server 2 don't show errors matching time of blocked requests.

What could be causing these packages to get dropped?

Server configuration:

`Web page (Server 2 Apache) -> Ruby http application (Server 1)`

Server 1 Ufw settings:

```
user@server1:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     DENY IN     Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
```

So only traffic to port `80` should be blocked. But is see following messages in Ufw log:

```
2021-01-11 23:13:00 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38424 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33158 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1157 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:00 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53629 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33084 DPT=8080 WINDOW=2160 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:00 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33158 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1157 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:01 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53630 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33084 DPT=8080 WINDOW=2160 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:01 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38426 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33158 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1157 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:02 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53631 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33084 DPT=8080 WINDOW=2160 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:02 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38427 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33158 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1157 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:03 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53632 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33084 DPT=8080 WINDOW=2160 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:03 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38428 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33158 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1157 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:06 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38429 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33158 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1157 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:26 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38431 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33158 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1157 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
2021-01-11 23:13:52 server1 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:..08:00 SRC=10.100.100.102 DST=10.100.100.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=38432 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33158 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1157 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
```

Active Iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 144 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    6082K   99G ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2    6082K   99G ufw-before-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
3    14402  875K ufw-after-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
4    13502  805K ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
5    13502  805K ufw-reject-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6    13502  805K ufw-track-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2        0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
3        0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
4        0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
5        0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6        0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    5789K  101G ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2    5789K  101G ufw-before-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
3     339K   21M ufw-after-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
4     339K   21M ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
5     339K   21M ufw-reject-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6     339K   21M ufw-track-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      900 70416 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
2        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
3        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
4        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
5        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
6        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
7        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
3        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
7        0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    4656K   99G ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
2    1345K  323M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    66677 3467K ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
4    66677 3467K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
9        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
10       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
11   14402  875K ufw-not-local  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
12       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
13       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
14   14402  875K ufw-user-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    4656K   99G ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            
2     794K 2513M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3     339K   21M ufw-user-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    40662 2114K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
2    19126  995K LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    13498  805K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2        4   144 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
3      900 70416 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
4        0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
5        0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      900 70416 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    13498  805K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
2        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     113K 6771K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
2     226K   14M ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:80

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
2        0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Apache proxy config on server 2:

```
<Location /app>
    ProxyPass http://10.100.100.101:8080/app retry=3
    ProxyPassReverse http://10.100.100.101:8080/app
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found another question which has explanation for this phenomenon: [Why is ufw logging 'BLOCK' messages regarding a port for which ufw is configured to 'ALLOW' connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299964/why-is-ufw-logging-block-messages-regarding-a-port-for-which-ufw-is-configured?rq=1)

This is more related to old connections being closed than actual client connections getting blocked. This explains why blocked connections did not have matching entries in access log of proxy server.